# PDO Pagination Error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, pagination

I have been working on pagination using pdo but i cannot seem to get past this part. i have looked up other posts and tutorials but i hit a wall, can anyone help? **Edit full code added, updates have been added but still has errors

```
<?php
try{
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=clients','root','');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}


?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>


<body bgcolor="#F5F1DE">

<div class="center">
  <br>
   <br>
    <br>
     <br>
      <br>
  <h2> Business Listings</h2>


<table  border="1" style="width:50%">
    <tr>
<?php
$per_page = 10;
$NoofRecords = $handler->query('SELECT COUNT(CompID) FROM Listings;');
$pages = ceil($NoofRecords / $per_page);

if(!isset($_GET['page'])){
    header(":location: Listings.php?page=1");
}
else{
    $page =$_GET['page'];
}

$start = (($page - 1)*$per_page);
echo "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE Accept=1 ORDER BY Premium LIMIT                  $start,$per_page;";
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE Accept=1 ORDER BY Premium LIMIT $start,$per_page;");
while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    echo '<td>', $r['Name'], '</td>','<td>', $r['Email'], '</td>','<td>',         $r['Phone'], '</td>',
'<td>','<a href="' . $r['Name'] . '.php">Company page</a>', '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}

for($number=1;$number<=$pages;$number++)
{
    echo '<a href="?page'.$number.'">.$number. </a>';
}   
echo"<BR>Current Page: $page"
?>

</table>
  </Div>
</div>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What issues are you having with this part?

Comment: on line 34 its does not like the syntax for ceil also on line 43 it complains aobut an undefined varrible adn then this "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1327 Undeclared variable: $start' in C:\wamp\www\Myserver\Listings.php on line 45
( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1327 Undeclared variable: $start in C:\wamp\www\Myserver\Listings.php on line 45"

Comment: put a try catch block around your pdo code.  var_dump the exception and you will see what is going wrong.

Comment: What does `echo $_GET['page'];` give you? Can you link to the tutorial, maybe seeing the original code will make debugging this quicker?

Comment: @chris85 [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhHdt8CM4LU)

Comment: Bah a video... okay nevermind that what does the echo give you?

Comment: @chris85 i echoed it and nothing appeared on the screen, not sure if error is covering it or it does nothing

Comment: Is there a question mark in the URL you are loading? Can you post the query string you are executing, after `.php` in the URL?

Comment: @chris85 ok i changed the url to "Listings.php?page=1" and most of the errors disappear , but one remains " Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in C:\wamp\www\Myserver\Listings.php on line 34". Thank you for putting up with me thus far, i have been bashing my head against this wall for 2 hours

Comment: Is the output of the query still `-10`?

Comment: it output "Current Page: 1"

Comment: no wait i am stupid it echoed "$pages = ceil($NoofRecords / $per_page)"

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following you. Please use the below code and let me know the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit goes last in your query.

```
SELECT * FROM listings WHERE Accept=1 ORDER BY Premium LIMIT $start,$per_page ;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

You also need to use double quotes as Crystal has pointed out for PHP to process the variables. You should use prepared statements though this is open to injections, [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Updated, without prepared statements which you should still use..

```
<?php
try{
    $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=clients','root','');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
    die();
}
$per_page = 10;
$NoofRecords = $handler->query('SELECT COUNT(CompID) as counted FROM Listings;');
$fetchdata = $NoofRecords->fetch();
$recordcount = $fetchdata['counted'];
$pages = ceil($recordcount / $per_page);
if(empty($_GET['page'])){
    //this is a waste if this page is listings.php, just set $page to 1;
    header("Location: Listings.php?page=1");
} else{
    $page = $_GET['page'];
}
$start = (($page - 1)*$per_page);
echo "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE Accept=1 ORDER BY Premium LIMIT $start,$per_page;";
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE Accept=1 ORDER BY Premium LIMIT $start,$per_page;");
while($r = $query->fetch()) {
    $table_contents = '<tr><td>' . $r['Name'] . '</td><td>' . $r['Email'] . '</td><td>'. $r['Phone'] . '</td><td><a href="' . $r['Name'] . '.php">Company page</a></td></tr>';
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor="#F5F1DE">
<div class="center"> 
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h2> Business Listings</h2>
    <table  border="1" style="width:50%"> 
        <?php echo $table_contents; ?>
    </table>
    <?php
    for($number=1;$number<=$pages;$number++) {
        echo '<a href="?page'.$number.'">'.$number. '</a>';
    }   
    echo "<BR>Current Page: $page"; ?>

</div>
</div><!-- I dont know what these 2 divs are for... -->
</div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you this worked , but there as an error that is hidden in the background behind the page content

Comment: Whats the error? Make sure to remove `echo "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE Accept=1 ORDER BY Premium LIMIT $start,$per_page;";`. Outputting content is a good way to diagnose and resolve errors in the future.

Comment: It returned an error "Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in C:\wamp\www\Myserver\Listings.php on line 11"

Comment: its a problem with converting the line "$pages = ceil($NoofRecords / $per_page);" into an int

Comment: Yes, just updated. You need to fetch the result from that query. Try updated code now.

Comment: New error , undefined variable in "    for($number=1;$number<=$pages;$number++) {"

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes `"` instead of single quotes `'` when using variables in a string:

```
"SELECT * FROM listings WHERE Accept=1 ORDER BY Premium LIMIT $start,$per_page;"
```

Comment: Fixed SQL statement. Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Changed query still getting erros ,"Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int line 34 " and Undefined variable line 43

Comment: Echo the statement and see what you are sending to the DB. `echo "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE Accept=1 ORDER BY Premium LIMIT $start,$per_page;";`

Comment: Do you have the rest of the code? There are only 27 lines here.

Comment: it gave the output "SELECT * FROM listings WHERE Accept=1 ORDER BY Premium LIMIT -10,10;"

Comment: The `-10` is your issue. `LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants (except when using prepared statements).` What is `$_GET['page']` equal to?

Comment: i am not sure what you mean, i was following a tutorial and everything went horribly worng

Answer (score 0):

change your query line to this: the query syntax was wrong.

```
$query = $handler->query("SELECT * FROM listings WHERE Accept=1 ORDER BY Premium LIMIT $start,$per_page");
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the sql problems mentioned in the other answers (`LIMIT` at the end, double quotes so that you can use variables in the string), you already have an earlier problem:

```
$pages = ceil(($NoofRecords,0)/$per_page);
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ What is supposed to happen here?
```

The `,0` part renders the whole statement invalid.

You just need:

```
$pages = ceil($NoofRecords / $per_page);
```